# Watch the number of children an element has?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I need to know if a custom element has gained or lost children.

I was hoping to use `observedAttributes()` and `attributeChangedCallback` to react when there was a change, but both `children` and `childNodes` are properties, not attributes.

Is there a way that I can watch for a change in a property and respond in the same way I can a change in an attribute?

I don't want to use libraries.

Code so far...

```
class MyElement extends HTMLElement
    constructor: ->
        super()
```

Comment: Any code we can see? LOL

Comment: How can I show you code for something that I haven't programmed?

Comment: How can you expect us to solve a problem you have if you have not done anything?

Comment: I've added the relevant code that I have so far. As you'll see, it's not going to provide any information as I'm asking a question about a fundamental technique, not a bug fix.

Answer (score 0):

If your number of children changes your props will change , so you can 'watch ' using for example a hook

```
useEffect(() => console.log(props.children.count));
```

Does that help?

Comment: I believe this will work when I'm adding children, as adding children is done in the context of the parent. But when I change the parent of the child, this won't trigger in the original parent.

I essentially need a way for an element to watch its own property and react when there is a change. I think I can do this with a Proxy object.

Comment: I am not sure I understand , you can add the hook to all the potential parents. You mean you want to update the original parent when the number of children in another component changes ,  could you use the context for that ? This might be useful https://dev.to/oieduardorabelo/react-hooks-how-to-create-and-update-contextprovider-1f68

Comment: So if I add a hook to parent A, and then the parent of its child changes to B, A will notice that it has lost a child and react?

Also are hooks part of React? I'd like to do this with vanilla JS.